# using np cut and raise error bins must increase on python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this :

```
Code    Notes   Qty
AAD     2A 2K   17
AAD     2A 1K    1 
AAG     2A 3K   12 
AAG     4A 4K    2
AAG     5A 5K    1
ALA     1A 2K   10
ALA     1A 1K    3
```

And my aim is to find class for EACH code, meaning Qty with biggest 80% of sum is Class 1, and rest 15% is class 2, and rest class 3. So, AAD sum is 18, that means AAD with 2A 2K (its cumsum 16 which is in scope of 80% of 18+4) is class 1 and AAD with 2A 1K is class 2. And so on.
Someone help me from my previous question to use pd.cut (I dont know if I am allowed to mention a username here). So I am trying to modified the code and apply to this new problem but the error says 'bins must increase monotically`.
This is my code

```
df['cumsum']=df.groupby('Code')['Qty'].cumsum()
total = df.groupby('Code')['Qty'].sum()
bins = [total*0.15,total*0.05,total*0.8]
labels = ['class3','class2','class1']
df['class']=pd.cut(df['cumsum'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
```

this is result I want to achieve :

```
Code    Notes   Qty   Class
AAD     2A 2K   17    class1
AAD     2A 1K    1    class2
AAG     2A 3K   12    class1 
AAG     4A 4K    2    class2
AAG     5A 5K    1    class3
ALA     1A 2K   10    class1
ALA     1A 1K    3    class2
```

Comment: Are you entirely sure of the first row ```AAD     2A 2K   14    class1```?

Comment: yes. it is more than 80% of sum which is 18 for AAD

Comment: I don't understand how your class should work, but something like that must do the work:  `df['Classe'] = pd.cut(df.groupby('Code')['Qty'].apply(lambda x: x/x.sum()),bins = [0,0.5,1], labels = ['c1','c2'])`

Comment: @beginner 14/18 is ~78%, not higher than 80% ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['class'] = pd.cut(df.groupby('Code')['Qty'].transform('sum').rdiv(df['Qty']), 
                     bins=[0, 0.15, 0.8, 1], labels=['class3', 'class2', 'class1'])
```

*NB. if you want 80% of the **total** per group, this doesn't match the provided output. Maybe you want 80% of the **maximum**? In which can use `transform('max')`.*

Output:

```
  Code  Notes  Qty   class
0  AAD  2A 2K   17  class1
1  AAD  2A 1K    1  class3
2  AAG  2A 3K   12  class2
3  AAG  4A 4K    2  class3
4  AAG  5A 5K    1  class3
5  ALA  1A 2K   10  class2
6  ALA  1A 1K    3  class2
```

If you want to use a [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) (which is not really what you describe):

```
df['class'] = pd.cut(df.groupby('Code')['Qty'].cumsum().rdiv(df['Qty']), 
                     bins=[0, 0.8, 1], labels=['class2', 'class1'])
```

Output:

```
  Code  Notes  Qty   class
0  AAD  2A 2K   14  class1
1  AAD  2A 1K    4  class2
2  AAG  2A 3K   12  class1
3  AAG  4A 4K   10  class2
4  AAG  5A 5K    4  class2
5  ALA  1A 2K   10  class1
6  ALA  1A 1K    8  class2
```

Comment: sorry for the confusing, 80% of total per group (AAD total is 18, AAG is 26, ALA is 18)

Comment: @beginner OK, 80% of 18 is 14.4, which is not compatible with your given output, can you correct or clarify?

Comment: @beginner I edited the answer based on your edited output but this is still not matching, please break down all calculations. Have you given it a try?

Comment: thanks, there is a mistake when in preprocessing data, but there is this one 
```
                                            Qty                          sum         cumsum
4302 AGA  2A2K 14323 class1 30613 14323
4301 AGA   2A1K 4810 class2 30613 19133
4303 AGA   2A3K 4180 class2 30613 23313
4306 AGA   2A4K 3759 class2 30613 27072
4307 AGA 32A5K 1472 class2 30613 28544
```
I put 95%, so 95%*sum is 29082.35 therefore until cumsum is 29082.5 should be in class1, until idx 4307 should be in class 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think you want to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': ['AAD', 'AAD', 'AAG', 'AAG', 'AAG', 'ALA', 'ALA'],
    'Notes': ['2A 2K', '2A 1K', '2A 3K', '4A 4K', '5A 5K', '1A 2K', '1A 1K'],
    'Qty': [14, 4, 12, 10, 1, 10, 8]
})

df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('Code')['Qty'].cumsum()
df['total'] = df.groupby('Code')['Qty'].transform('sum')
df['class'] = np.where(df['cumsum'] <= df['total']*0.8, 'class1', 
                       np.where(df['cumsum'] <= df['total']*0.95, 'class3', 'class2'))

df = df.drop(['cumsum', 'total'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

which returns:

```
 Code  Notes  Qty   class
0  AAD  2A 2K   14  class1
1  AAD  2A 1K    4  class2
2  AAG  2A 3K   12  class1
3  AAG  4A 4K   10  class2
4  AAG  5A 5K    1  class2
5  ALA  1A 2K   10  class1
6  ALA  1A 1K    8  class2
```